# Package react-native-webview has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-webview

here is the version
Old Version =>  "react-native-webview": "^11.17.2",
New Version => "react-native-webview": "^11.18.0"

I am using webview to render html but it requires or depend on an other lib

```
react-native-test-app

here is the warning I got


warn Package react-native-webview has been ignored because it contains invalid configuration. Reason: Cannot find module 'react-native-test-app/package.json'
```

Require stack:

- /Volumes/companyData/Meta_Quiz_App_ReactNative/node_modules/react-native-webview/react-native.config.js
- /Volumes/companyData/Meta_Quiz_App_ReactNative/node_modules/import-fresh/index.js
- /Volumes/companyData/Meta_Quiz_App_ReactNative/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/loaders.js
- /Volumes/companyData/Meta_Quiz_App_ReactNative/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/createExplorer.js
- /Volumes/companyData/Meta_Quiz_App_ReactNative/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/index.js
- /Volumes/companyData/Meta_Quiz_App_ReactNative/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/tools/config/readConfigFromDisk.js
- /Volumes/companyData/Meta_Quiz_App_ReactNative/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/tools/config/index.js
- /Volumes/companyData/Meta_Quiz_App_ReactNative/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/install/install.js
- /Volumes/companyData/Meta_Quiz_App_ReactNative/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/index.js
- /Volumes/companyData/Meta_Quiz_App_ReactNative/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js
- /Volumes/companyData/Meta_Quiz_App_ReactNative/node_modules/react-native/cli.js

when I install this

```
npm i react-native-test-app
```

then its work fine for android but for ios it causing pods issue.
if I go back to old version it is still exists.
Thanks in advance please waiting for your help

Comment: do you have a package.json file in your react-native-test-app directory? Seems like that is what the error message is saying the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like version **11.18.0** is buggy and this issue provokes problems on the linking. The recomendation for now is to **downgrade 11.17.2**, you can read more at their [git repo related issues](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/2421) & [2430](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/2430)

Comment: I downgrade this its working for android and ios both. Thanks for sharing those links but this warning still exists

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade your package version as this issue has been resolved in version 11.18.1.

https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/releases/tag/v11.18.1

Answer (score -1):

`11.18.0` This version doesn't work very well.

`11.17.2` This version doesn't work very well.

I  use  `11.15.0`

> `yarn remove react-native-webview`

> `yarn  add react-native-webview@11.15.0`
>
> cd  ios
>
> pod install

[Yarn Version List](https://www.yarnpkg.cn/package/react-native-webview)